# Solving a matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this Algebra problem... I've just learned basic stuff (trace, transposed matrices, symmetric matrices, etc). Must solve for $X$:

$$
AX - \operatorname{tr}(C)X + X^T = B^*A
$$

I know that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, and the trace of $C$ is a real number.

I'd like some tips on how to tackle this kind of problems; I'd really appreciate if somebody could also give me a good resource for studying matrices.

Comment: The first thing I would do is to compress the redundant information. With $D=A-\operatorname{tr}(C)I$ and $E=B^*A$, the equation has the form $DX+X^T=E$. Already, it looks a little less daunting … One small observation: If $D=I$, only the symmetric part of $X$ can be determined.

Comment: Is $B^*A$ the product of $B$ and $A$?

Comment: @mfl The asterisk is in the exponent, so the answer is clearly no. $B^*$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $B$ (if not, it should have been clearly stated what it is).

Comment: $$ B^*A $$ is the product of (B-conjugate-transpose)(A): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen And what happens with $ X^T $ ?

Comment: Do you know the shapes of the matrices (if rows are less, equal or more than the columns)?

Comment: @ja72 Yes, all matrices have same dimensions.

Comment: I think the most general problem is $$A X + B X^\top + C =0$$

Comment: @ja72 well, it would be $AX + BX^T = C$, at any rate

Comment: Yes. Also I think `\top` works better that `T` for the transpose symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a square matrix, then there exists a non-singular symetric matrix $D$ such that $DX = X^T$. [1]
Then one can rewrite the equation like

$$(A + \text{tr}(C)I + D)X = B^*A$$

Now if $A + \text{tr}(C)I + D$ is non-singular, you have

$$X =(A + \text{tr}(C)I + D)^{-1} B^*A $$

I should think about what happens when it is not singular...

[1] http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1103039127

Comment: I don't think you know $D$ unless you know what $X$ is.

Comment: I think some of this is unnecessary since $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. Can't we do $(A+tr(C)I+I)X$ ?

Comment: I think you misread the results of the referenced paper. Your claim implies that $X$ and $X^T$ have the same null space, and that is not true in general.

Comment: Taking into account that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, isn't $X=(A-tr(C)I+I)^-1(B^*A)$ ?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Well there is written that "there is a symmetric matrix transforming $A$ into its transpose $A^\top$. Isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: @matr From the fact that $A$ and $B$ are symetric, how do you conclude that $X$ is? (which is what you seem to be assuming in  those passages) :)

Comment: The transform in the paper was a similarity transform. And that is not what you wrote. If you still don't agree, please tell me what matrix $D$ gives you $DX=X^T$ when $X=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Ah, I see. You're right then.. I should try to understand the meaning of the paper then! :)